# Conditional Expectation for Random Variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

How do you prove that $E(Y|X) = E(Y|E(Y|X))$ for any random variables $X,Y$? I tried using properties of conditional expectation like $E(E(Y|X)) = E(Y)$, but I'm not making much progress.

Is there an intuitive explanation for why this is true?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, you can think of $E(Y\mid X)$ as "our best estimate of $Y$'s value, given $X$" and it's pretty clear that "our best estimate for $Y$'s value, given our best estimate of $Y$'s value given $X$" should be the same as that estimate.

Concrete example:

1. For the left-hand side, you are a meteorologist. You are asked: "Given that today it's $X = 5^\circ$ outside, what is your prediction for tomorrow's temperature ($Y$)?" And maybe you answer $7^\circ$. (In general, $E(Y\mid X)$ is a function that maps today's temperature $X$ to a prediction of tomorrow's.)
2. For the right-hand side, you are a meteorologist. You are told: "Five minutes ago, I told you the temperature outside, and asked you to predict tomorrow's temperature. You answered $7^\circ$. Then I wiped your memory. Given only what you answered then, what is your prediction for tomorrow's temperature?" You should obviously (assuming I'm honest) answer $7^\circ$.

---

For a formal proof, take [Wikipedia's definition of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2).

The characterizing property of $E(Y\mid X)$ is that it's a whatever-measurable function of $X$ satisfying, for any measurable $f$,
$$
    \int E(Y\mid X) f(X)\,\text{d}P = \int Y f(X)\,\text{d}P.
$$
In particular, this implies that for any measurable function $f$,
$$
    \int E(Y\mid X) f(E(Y\mid X))\,\text{d}P = \int Y f(E(Y\mid X))\,\text{d}P
$$
because $f(E(Y\mid X))$ is also measurable function of $X$. So $E(Y\mid X)$ satisfies the characterizing property of $E(Y\mid E(Y \mid X))$, so it agrees with $E(Y\mid E(Y \mid X))$ almost always.

---

One "high-level" proof of this fact is as follows. The "tower property" of conditional expectation says that in general $E(E(A\mid B)\mid C) = E(A \mid C)$ when $C$ is $B$-measurable (intuitively, when knowing the value of $B$ tells you $C$).

In particular, $E(Y\mid X)$ is $X$-measurable. So we have
$$
   E(E(Y\mid X) \mid E(Y\mid X)) = E(Y \mid E(Y\mid X))
$$
by applying the tower property with $A = Y$, $B=X$, $C = E(Y\mid X)$. But $E(A\mid A)=A$ for any $A$, so $E(E(Y\mid X) \mid E(Y\mid X))$ simplifies to $E(Y\mid X)$, and we conclude that $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y \mid E(Y\mid X))$ as desired.

Comment: Why is $f(E(Y|X))$ a function of $X$?

Comment: Because $E(Y\mid X)$ is a function of $X$, and then you're just applying $f$ on top of that.

Comment: Why is $E(Y|X)$ a function of $X$? Note that you will have to write $E(Y|X)$ in the form $g\circ X$.

Comment: ...by definition?

Comment: Nope. The definition just says that it is a function with some characterizing property. Note  that $X$ is itself a function of $\omega$.

Comment: I assume we're both referring to Wikipedia's definition. (If you're thinking of another source, tell me.) It says: "Let $g \colon U \to \mathbb R^n$ be a $\Sigma$-measurable function such that [conditions]. Then the random variable $g(Y)$, denoted as $E(X\mid Y)$, is a conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$." In any case, it's crucial to understanding conditional expectation that the value of $E(Y\mid X)$ is entirely determined by $X$.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I only looked at your characterizing identity - not at Wikipedia. So, you are right.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without invoking the so-called measurable function?

Comment: If we're talking about random variables in full generality, we're talking about measure theory, no way around it. (If our random variables are discrete, we can avoid it.) You can probably do it by invoking known properties of conditional expectation instead, but that depends more than anything on what you consider to be a known property. I'll edit my answer to add an argument like that in.